# DBnull issue when converting empty string to number

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am trying to connect with Oracle and sending parameters as part of store procedure. Two of my parameters are coming as empty string so I need to pass null values but the datatype is set as number in the db end. When ever I run the script it gives me error that "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types".

Here is my code snippet remember string Case, string SRE_Pricing are coming in as "" .So I need to convert to number if there is anyting in text like "52" and if "" then assign DB null.

```
 OracleParameter CaseParam = new OracleParameter("arg_CASE_NUMBER", OracleType.Number);
                CaseParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                if (Case != null || Case!="")
                {
                    CaseParam.Value = Convert.ToInt32((Case.Equals(string.Empty)) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Case);
                }
                else
                {
                    CaseParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                //CaseParam.Value =Convert.ToInt32(Case);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(CaseParam);

                OracleParameter SRE_pricingParam = new OracleParameter("arg_SRE_PRICING_ELEMENT", OracleType.Number);
                SRE_pricingParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                if (SRE_Pricing != null || SRE_Pricing != "")
                {
                    SRE_pricingParam.Value = Convert.ToInt32((SRE_Pricing.Equals(string.Empty)) ? (object)DBNull.Value : SRE_Pricing);
                }
                else
                {
                    SRE_pricingParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                //SRE_pricingParam.Value = Convert.ToInt32(SRE_Pricing);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(SRE_pricingParam);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14psc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` operator instead of `||` in the `if` condition

```
if (SRE_Pricing != null && SRE_Pricing != "")
{
    SRE_pricingParam.Value = Convert.ToInt32(SRE_Pricing);
}
else
{
    SRE_pricingParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Better to use [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int price;
if (Int32.TryParse(SRE_Pricing, out price))
{
    SRE_pricingParam.Value = price;
}
else
{
    SRE_pricingParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: it still gives me this error +  $exception {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_T1_LINECHARGE'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n"} System.Exception {System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException}

Comment: @kam, Check the no of parameters your proc accept and no of parameters you are passing and there __datatypes__

Comment: I have added a picture in post to show u parameters and datatypes. if you could see. I believe they are same.